# Passing Data to view - Undefined variable

Tags: php, variables, laravel, undefined

I'm new to the Laravel Framework and I somehow got an issue that bothers me for days now.

I just wanted to pass a simple variable to a blade view, but any version that I found in any documentation or question on this platform unfortunately didn't lead to a solution.

I created a route which looks like this:

```
Route::get('test', 'PageController@index');
```

The Code in the `PageController` looks like this:

```
public function index(){
   $datatopass='datahere';
   return view('admin.test', compact('datatopass'));
}
```

And then I got the View that looks like this:

```
@section('content')
{{$datatopass}}
@stop
```

The problem is that I get 2 Exeptions:

```
#ErrorException in d9e848d01f99ac2368ead804bd322152 line 3:
Undefined variable: datatopass (View: /home/vagrant/test/resources/views/admin/test.blade.php)

ErrorException in d9e848d01f99ac2368ead804bd322152 line 3:
Undefined variable: datatopass
```

I'm using homestead development environment which is set up in a VirtualBox.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

I really tried every type of datapassing like

```
return view('test')->with('datatopass', $datatopass)` 
//or
return view('datatopass', $datatopass)
```

and so on.

I'll be greateful for your help.

Comment: Weird, the `->with()` and `compact` ones should work. Have you tried `dd($datatopass)` just before you return your view? What does it say?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't load this view in different places other than  PageController?

Comment: Yes the testpage ist just started by the PageController. And about dd(): no output here. Did I call it right.`PageController`  `public function index(){
   $datatopass='datahere';
   dd($datatopass);
}`

Comment: Try to do `php artisan view:clear` to reset views cache

Comment: There is no such namespace as `view` defined for php artisan

Comment: When you installer laravel did you run a composer install?

Comment: Yes everything was installed by composer

Comment: Which Laravel Framework version are you using? Can you run `php artisan -V and ensure your framework is 5.*? php artisan view:clear must be available if your are using L5. Your problem looks like a view cache issue. Are you including any partial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this::

```
return view('test')->with('datatopass', $datatopass);
```

And in View access it as

```
<?php echo $datatopass ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I already solved the problem. Something was wrong in my `route.php` so the data wasn't passed to the right view.